# Eyes and visor is metallic

Tags: modeling, rendering

I downloaded a model of Peridot from Steven Universe, however when I opened it in Blender, both the eyes and the visor had a metallic look to them. I'm new to using Blender, so I have absolutely no idea what to do.

[image]
[image]

Comment: For us to better help you, consider editing your answer to include example images of the problem you are having. From your description you might be in shaded mode not render mode. Try switching to cycles render view mode which supports transparency. Otherwise there may not be a shader set up for transparency on your model yet.

Comment: I've edited it with the pictures. Also, I've tried going into cycles, but it didn't help. It apparently worked on versions 2.7 and I think 2.8, if that helps.

Comment: sharing the blend files would help in understanding the issue.. Most probably it might be related to transparency settings ..

Comment: I figured it out. I didn't realize that if I click on "render image," it would look completely different than how it looks in shading (despite already being told that.) My bad, guys. I'm a dummy.

Comment: In the Eevee render settings, enable *Screen Space Reflection* and *Screen Space Reflection > Refraction*. Then the eyes and visor should look transparent/glass-like in the viewport.